# Looping and saving data into the same table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looping through 5 data frames (space separated) and doing some calculations or modifications. After the calculation is done on the first table I would like to save results into the same table by overwriting it and repeat this for all 5 data frames.

At the moment I am know how to write the first part:

`table = sorted(glob.glob('*.dat'))`

```
for i in table:
    data = pd.read_table(i, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=range(5))
    here I am doing some calculation
    and here I would like to save data into the same table by overwriting (but I do not know how)
```

Any advice or help is more than welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward. Let me know if you are looking for anything else.

```
# sample dataframes
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [5., 6., 7., 8.], 'two' : [9., 10., 11., 12.]})
d3 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [15., 16., 17., 18.], 'two' : [19., 10., 11., 12.]})

# list of dataframes
mydfs = [d1, d2, d3]

for i in mydfs:
    i['three'] = i['one'] + i['two']
    print(i)
```

If you check the dataframes after running the above code, you will see each of the dataframes will have column 'three'

Comment: Hmmm I think this does not solve my problem ... no need to add new column just to overwrite the old table with the new one, that way the name of the table will stay the same.

Comment: In the code I've mentioned above, the name of the table will stay the same as we're just looping the names through the for loop. If you don't want to create new column names, you can use the existing column names for doing calculations(eg. df['one'] = df['one'] + df['two']). I've just used column 'three' for demonstration purpose.